# Android Show Video capturing preview on same screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to display and record a video simultaneously on Android screen.But i want the camera to open not full screen rather on half area of screen and some button on other half.

I have googled it but have been unable to find any help. How can i get the preview from camera on half area of screen(vertical/horizontal).
Using Android Studio. Min SDK "10".

Comment: have you tried any UI for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not distort video aspect ratio you can use following approach: create full-size camera preview, then cover the second half of screen with some solid layout. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <!-- Layout for controls right on camera preview -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="#000">

            <!-- Layout for other controls on your screen -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: android:id="@+id/camera_preview"  is it same as VideoView . as i only have videoview option in widgets no cameraview